# Communication between injected class service (AppState) and components

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I want to figure out what's the best approach to send re-render requests to a component when an application wide class' (AppState pattern) property has changed.

Following this [nice blog post](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/) from Chris Sainty, the third example is exactly the kind of thing I want to achieve.

Have a singleton/scoped service, AppState, with the main purpose to store session data to be consumed by several components, invoking an event action when one of it's properties changes, after getting some data from an external api for example. The component can then listen to that and call `StateHasChanged()` to re-render the page.

This works but I have a couple of questions about the method.

1. Is it the best approach for doing this or are there more appropriate
   ways implemented into the language by default? Either for the event based communication or the whole AppState service. I'd imagine this is quite a common problem and perhaps I'm missing some default functionality like `@bind`.
2. Are there any drawbacks to `@implements IDisposable`? I understand why
   it needs to be disposed of, but why don't we need to do it when, for
   instance, binding some data to an input field to essentially do the
   same thing? Does the `@bind` attribute already handle that under the hood?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I'm missing something obvious, still learning the ropes of Blazor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the best approach for doing this or are there more appropriate
> ways implemented into the language by default?

For Communication between unrelated components, we have different options:

1. `AppState` registered as Scoped/Singleton. (extra overhead of registering and disposing event).
2. `AppState` as `razor` file (code example is given below).
3. Follow `MVVM` pattern for storing `state`, but there is downside to this approach we need to inject every `view model` as `Scoped/Singleton`. (If we are re using same component multiple times then each component state will be same).

Based on the requirement you can choose the best.

**Example for AppState as razor file (preserving state of counter)**

`App.razor` will look like this:

```
<AppState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</AppState>
```

and `AppState.razor` will look like this:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private int _count;

    [Parameter]
    public required RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }//use 'required' only if .net version is 7 & above

    public int Count
    {
        get => _count; 
        set
        {
            _count = value;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and Counter.razor will look like this:

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @State.Count</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public required AppState State { get; set; }//use 'required' only if .net version is 7 & above

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        State.Count++;
    }
}
```

> Are there any drawbacks to @implements IDisposable?

No, only an extra overhead, we need to dispose all unmanged resource manually.

Comment: Very interesting and straightforward solution. I guess the only drawback from that method is the loss of granularity you get in case you want several State classes to separate concerns. In the meantime I also found [this example](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/main/samples/aspnetcore/blazor/FlightFinder/FlightFinder.Client) that also implements AppState as a class pattern, I should test both solutions and see which one is appropriate for the case. I'll wait a few hours to see if someone want's to chime in otherwise I'll accept the answer. Thanks for sharing!